# Evaluating a Javascript file, expression by expression, in a NodeJS repl

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have these two lines:

```
var a = 1;

console.log(a);
```

I want some means to send the first line to the NodeJS repl, have it evaluate, then send the second line.

I've tried the default NodeJS repl, the chrome and firefox browser tools, and IntelliJ interactive scripting but they're all unfriendly.

For the NodeJS repl and browsers, you need to shift-enter for multiline. For IntelliJ, it can't recognize console.log (probably because it's not a true NodeJS environment).

Can you suggest some other tool?

Comment: If you could find one that didn't submit when pressing enter, that may work, but that'd be a bit weird. shift enter is pretty standard for multiline, and enter is pretty standard for submitting a line, so.... not quite sure what you're expecting.

Comment: So the IntelliJ one works like this: you type your code in a file. If it's a single line, you press ctrl-enter and it evaluates. If it's multiline, you highlight all the lines, and then hit ctrl-enter.

I've worked with other language REPLs which operate in the same manner.

Comment: The IntelliJ one is good. It just doesn't support console.log which I need.

Comment: hmm... i could see something like that being done as a plugin in one of the common editors (vscode/sbtext) but you'd likely run into the same problem, where does the console output go.

Comment: I believe in the previous tools I'd use, the REPL started as a separate process, and the text editor would pipe it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Emacs, there is [nodejs-repl.el](https://github.com/abicky/nodejs-repl.el).

As the github page shows, if you define the following key bindings:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key js-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-e") 'nodejs-repl-send-last-sexp)
            (define-key js-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-r") 'nodejs-repl-send-region)
            (define-key js-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'nodejs-repl-load-file)
            (define-key js-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-z") 'nodejs-repl-switch-to-repl)))
```

You can use Ctrl-c + Ctrl-r to send a highlighted region of code to the REPL pretty much like IntelliJ's Ctrl-Enter.

Of course, you need to install the node.js dependencies for the REPL to work in Emacs.